# Gson Date deserialize issue

Tags: android, date, serialization, gson

I am trying serialize and deserialize object Date, but deserialize are without success. What is bad? Thx

```
Gson gson = Gson();
String date = gson.toJson(new Date());                  
Date d = gson.fromJson(date, Date.class);
```

Answer (score 0):

You are missing the `new` keyword when invoking the Gson constructor. Otherwise, this code sample seems to work as intended. Perhaps providing more detail on the issue that you are having can help us answer your question better.